# How to pass json into request POST method for Coinbase API

Tags: python, python-3.x, coinbase-api

I am trying to send some json parameters into my REST call. When calling the API without any json, all the responses are returned as required.

When i introduce the json parameters, the code throws the following error:

```
 File "coinbase.py", line 32, in __call__
    message = timestamp + request.method + request.path_url + (request.body or '')
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

Please find the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json, hmac, hashlib, time, requests, sys
from requests.auth import AuthBase
from urllib.error import HTTPError

API_KEY = 'ABC'
API_SECRET = '234'


# Create custom authentication for Coinbase API
class CoinbaseWalletAuth(AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, api_key, secret_key):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.secret_key = secret_key

    def __call__(self, request):
        timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
        print(f'timestamp type {type(timestamp)}')
        print(f'request method type - {type(request.method)}')
        print(f'request path url {type(request.path_url)}')
        print(f'request body - {type(request.body)}')
        message = timestamp + request.method + request.path_url + (request.body or '')
        signature = hmac.new(bytes(self.secret_key , 'latin-1'), bytes(message , 'latin-1'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

        request.headers.update({
            'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signature,
            'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
            'CB-ACCESS-KEY': self.api_key,
            'CB-VERSION' : '2021-01-05'
        })

        return request


def buy_crypto(ccy, auth):
    try:
        print('we are in buy crypto method')
        tx = {"amount": "1.00", "currency": "GPB", "payment_method": "87637836473"}
        r = requests.post("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/1562576532/buys", json=tx, auth=auth)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            print(f'We have bought {ccy}')
    except HTTPError as err:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Starting coinbase app')
    auth =  CoinbaseWalletAuth(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
    buy_crypto('BTC', auth)
```

The code returns the following types: 
timestamp type <class 'str'> 
request method type - <class 'str'> 
request path url <class 'str'> 
request body - <class 'bytes'>

My question is why is the request body being set as bytes? If this was a string, I believe the code would work. Any suggestions?

Comment: before sending data python has to convert string to bytes and maybe `body` keeps data aready ready to send (already converted to bytes to send them) And use `request.body.decode()` to get string.

Answer (score 2):

Since `request.body` comes as a bytes should concatenate like so:

```
def __call__(self, request):
    timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
    message = (timestamp + request.method + request.path_url).encode("utf-8")
    if request.body:
        message=b''.join([message, request.body])
    signature = hmac.new(self.secret_key, message, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

    request.headers.update({
        'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signature,
        'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
        'CB-ACCESS-KEY': self.api_key,
        'CB-VERSION' : '2020-06-16'
    })
    return request
```

Comment: Been struggling with this exact problem over 3 weekends, thanks for the succinct answer and full code example

Comment: @Pete , it is a pleasure to hear it helped you.